# assign bytes to RGB Color

Tags: c#, bitmap

I tried to assign byte to RGB color but I got this error in VS2010 "Property or indexer 'System.Drawing.Color.R' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only"
so how can I assign byte to RGB color ?

Comment: Can you show us your code - the offending line plus a couple of lines either side. It will help us guide you in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to assign this property. Instead you should create new `Color` instance:

```
Color oldColor;
byte r;
Color newColor = Color.FromArgb(oldColor.A, r, oldColor.G, oldColor.B);
```

Comment: is newColor now is Color Type or what ?